# Problems with autocomplete for graphQl query with Apollo server on a typescript/React app

Tags: reactjs, graphql, vite, apollo-client

I am trying grapqhQL for the first time.
For that I am using the graphql API `https://rickandmortyapi.com/graphql`
I created my app with *Vite* , and set up the Apollo Client.
I tried my first query and it works.
Now I am trying to get the autocompletion to work, but I simply can't.

I installed the VSCode extensions :

```
"graphql.vscode-graphql",
"graphql.vscode-graphql-syntax"
```

I created a `.graphqlrc` file :

```
{
   schema: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/graphql"
}
```

But i don't get the autocompletion and from *GrapQL Language Server* i get the error :`WARNING: graphql-config error, only highlighting is enabled: GraphQL Config file is not available in the provided config directory: /Users/.../test_graphql`

in case it is relevat

My `tsConfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

And my `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "test_graphql",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "codegen": "graphql-codegen --verbose --config codegen.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.17",
    "graphql": "^16.7.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^4.0.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/near-operation-file-preset": "^2.5.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^4.0.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^4.0.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^3.3.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.61.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.61.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.0"
  }
}
```

I would much appreciate any lead, I've spent 10 hours trying to figure it out.

I tried with the official extension from Apollo, *Apollo GraphQL* , with *GraphQL for VSCode* (  publisher:"Kumar Harsh"), following a similar question found here, also tried installing and setting up *ts-graphql-plugin*  .

I created different versions of a config file using the possible syntaxes : `graphql.config.yml`, `.graphqlrc.yml` and `.graphqlrc.ts`

All to no avail